# How to call a function with a class object as a parameter in string form

Tags: python

```
class host_struct(object):
   host_id = dict()
   host_license_id = dict()

def m(a):
   eval(a)

host = host_struct()
m('host.host_id={1:1}')
print host
```

The above code doesn't work and is a sample of what I am trying to accomplish.  I am trying to solve a problem where I need to call a function with a class object as a string, yet in the function manipulate the object as a class.

Here is my problem:  I have a connection pooler/broker module, that maintains a persistent connection to the server.  The server sets a inactivity TTL on all connections of 30 minutes.  So every 29 minutes the broker need to touch the server to maintain a persistent connection.  At the same time the connection broker needs to process client requests which it will send to the server and when the server responds, send the server's reply to the client.

The communications to the server are via a connection class that has many complex objects.  So allowing the client modules to directly manipulate the class would bypass the connection broker entirely which will result in the server terminating the connection due to the inactivity TTL.

Is this possible?  Is there a better way to address this problem?

Here is some additional background. I am opening a connection to VMWare vCenter.  To initiate the connection, I instantiate the connection class, then call a connection method.  Currently in my client programs, I am doing all of this now.  However I am running into a problem with vCenter and need to connect once when I start the program and use the same connection for the entire run.  Currently I am opening a connection to vCenter do my work, close the connection and sleep for a period of time then repeat the process.  This continual connect/disconnect is causing issues.  So I wrote a test to see if I could address the issues my maintaining a persistent connection and I was successful.

```
vcenter = VIServer()
vcenter.connect(*config_values)
```

At this point, the vcenter object is connected to the server.  There are several method calls I need to make to query certain objects.  Here are 2 examples of the many I use:

```
vms = vcenter._retrieve_properties_traversal(property_names=vm_objects,obj_type='VirtualMachine')
or
api_version = vcenter.get_api_version()
```

The first line will retrieve specific VM objects from the server and the second gets the API version.  I would like to call this method from the connection broker because he will be the one that is keeping the connection to vCenter open.

So in my connection broker I would like to pass 'vcenter.get_api_version()' as a string argument and have the connection broker execute api = vcenter.get_api_version().

Does this help to clarify?

Comment: I don't really understand the connection between your quetion and your explanation of the situation.  Why does that connection broker setup require you to pass statements around as strings?

Comment: Your code works if you use `exec a`, but why do you feel you need to use `eval`/`exec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [exec](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) instead of eval. Example:

```
class host_struct: # no need for parentheses if not inheriting from something besides object
    host_id = {} # use of {} is more idiomatic than dict()
    host_license_id = {}

def m(a):
    exec a

host = host_struct()
m('host.host_id.update({1:1})') # updating will add to existing dict instead of replacing

print host.host_id[1]
```

Running this script produces the expecte output of `1`.